# Sorting an array of struct objects using two parameters in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have the following code:

```
struct MyData {
    var company = String();
    var score:Int;
}

let data = [
    MyData(company: "smiths", score: 4 ),
    MyData(company: "lukes", score: 4),
    MyData(company: "lukes", score: 9)
]

extension MyData: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "(\(company), \(score))"
    }
}

data.sorted { ($0.company, $1.score) < ($1.company, $0.score) }
print(data)
```

My output is:

> [(smiths, 4), (lukes, 4), (lukes, 9)]

However, I want it to be the other way around:

> [(lukes, 9), (lukes, 4), (smiths, 4)]

Can someone show me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So your sorting rule should be: 1) first sort alphabetically based on the company 2) if the company is the same, sort based on the score? By the way, you are printing your original array. `sorted` returns a new array containing the sorted results, it's not a mutating function. It couldn't even work with a  mutating function, since `data` is immutable.

Comment: If the sort is reversed, change `<` to `>`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sort by `company` ascending then by `score` descending.

First of all – as mentioned in the comments – you have to assign the result to a new variable, `print(data)` prints the unsorted original array.

The sort algorithm is supposed to be

*if the companies are equal sort the scores descending otherwise sort the companies ascending*

```
let sortedData = data.sorted { ($0.company == $1.company) ? $0.score > $1.score : $0.company < $1.company}
print(sortedData)
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to assign sorted data to a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sorting rule described in comments, this is how your custom sorting function should look like:

```
let sorted = data.sorted(by: { this, next in
    if this.company < next.company {
        return true //first sort based on ascending company name
    } else if this.company == next.company {
        return this.score > next.score //if company name is the same, sort by descending score
    } else {
        return false //if company name is later in the alphabet, put it later in the sorted output
    }
})
print(sorted)
```

Output:

> [(lukes, 9), (lukes, 4), (smiths, 4)]

Moreover, the code you used didn't work for two reasons: sorted returns a new array containing the sorted results, it's not a mutating function. It couldn't even work with a mutating function, since data is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that my solution was almost there.  Because the sorted function returns a new array, and doesn't actually sort the array it is being called on, my print statement was always printing the original collection.  The solution to my problem was:

```
var myArray = data.sorted { ($0.company, $1.score) < ($1.company, $0.score) }
print(myArray)
```

Thanks very much for the help.  :-)